# ¿Cómo permitir de forma segura la inserción de etiquetas P en una Textarea?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando que el contenido que un usuario escriba en una **textarea** sea escrito en un fichero mediante el método `fwrite()`.

Hasta ahora todo marcha perfecto excepto que cuando visualizo como pagina web el fichero generado y escrito por el usuario, éste no muestra los saltos de linea que sí hizo en la `textarea`.

Obviamente es porque le faltan etiquetas `<p></p>` a su escrito.
Al inicio quería solucionar este problema englobando su contenido con el método `nl2br()` pero no me parece muy profesional dado que dicho método tiene un interlineado que uno no puede controlar.

En cambio si englobo el contenido del usuario con etiquetas **p** voy a poder controlar el interlineado, **padding**, a la perfección.

Por lo tanto quiero permitir que el usuario inserte etiquetas `<p></p>` en la `textarea`, pero mi temor es que esto sea inseguro, puesto que existen funciones en `PHP` orientadas a escapar estas etiquetas, como por ejemplo `htmlspecialchars()` que es un método que yo uso para escapar los caracteres `HTML`.

Entonces no se como evitar este conflicto, por un lado necesito escapar caracteres extraños y por otro necesito que el usuario inserte párrafos.

**Tal vez alguien sepa otro método para hacer esto (quizá generar párrafos dinámicamente) y no hacer que el usuario mismo los escriba.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Obtener las líneas del texto separando el mismo por saltos de líneas (`eg: \n`).
- Iterar el arreglo de líneas, y a cada línea, aplicarle la limpieza que fuera necesaria (`ej: htmlspecialchars($texto);`) y englobar el texto resultante entre `<p></p>`.
- Luego que unimos todas las líneas y listo.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$mensaje = "Hola!\n\r\n\rQuiero saber mas sobre el producto.<script src=\"https://dangerhost.com/malware.js\"></script>\n\r\n\rSaludos.";
$lineas = explode("\n", $mensaje);
$html = '';

foreach($lineas as $linea) {
    $texto = trim($linea);
    // Si el text esta vacio
    if (!$texto) continue;
    // Escapamos los caracteres HTML
    $texto = htmlspecialchars($texto);
    // Agregamos los tag <p>
    $html .= '<p>'.$texto.'</p>'."\n";
}
echo $html;
```

---

#### Referencias:

- [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php): Divide un `string` en varios `string`.
- [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php): Elimina espacio en blanco (u otro tipo de caracteres) del inicio y el final de la cadena.

Comment: No entiendo. No me gusta copiar y pegar un código que no es mio. Lo que procuro siempre es entender el código y luego hacerlo yo mismo. Pero en este caso como que se complica demasiado, no entiendo qué pinta ahí el implode, explode y el array_map... Si pudieras hacer por favor un ejemplo más sencillo, digamos básico, sin mucha cosa, sólo para entender los principios.

Comment: Lo que me confundió fue el **array_map** que, no es de uso común. **implode** y **explode** los entiendo. Muy original eso de combinar el **\n** con el **explode**, eso fue lo que hizo la magia. Y Eso es lo mas importante. Ya lo entendi y practique. Gracias. Una ultima duda que tengo es: Ese *\n* solo es compatible con Linux y Mac, pero para Windows solo sirve el **\r\n**, por lo tanto ¿cual deberia usar?

Comment: Y cuando suba este ejemplo a mi servidor ¿que entiende el servidor: **\n** o **\r\n**? No se si me explico. Yo quiero evitar que haya alguna incompatibilidad, quiero que mi salto de linea sea soportado por todos. Supongo que cuando éste codigo esté subido en mi web, no importara con que sistema operativo ingrese los datos el usuario (vía textarea) sino que solo importara lo que soporte mi servidor ¿estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: @user137527, no. Los saltos de línea que ingresen en el `textarea` serán dependiendo el sistema operativo que emplee el usuario. Lo que debes entender es que `\r` es un caracter y `\n` es otro. Windows usa los 2 caracteres y Unix solo `\n`. Si usas `\n` para obtener las líneas, funcionara en ambos sistemas.

Comment: Hola Marcos, tengo otro problema referente a este mismo asunto. ¿podemos hablar por el chat o debo abrir otro tema?.. Es sobre el segundo parametro del **fwrite(p1, p2)**, que no me interpreta el **foreach()**, como sí hace con las variables. Por lo tanto no puedo iterar los valores del **explode**. O sea en la pagina 1 funciona perfectamente, pero en la pagina 2, que es a donde envio los datos del usuario en un nuevo fichero, ahi no funciona. El segundo parametro de *fwrite()* tampoco me interpreta correctamente las funciones. Parece que solo acepta variables.

Comment: @user137527 sin ver el código se me hace difícil entender y darte una solución. Puede que sea una buena idea abrir una nueva pregunta planteando el nuevo problema que se te esta presentando.

Comment: Ya creé otro tema con el nuevo problema.